# Single Page Application

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am having a problem with Domino Designer and, to be honest, am not sure if the question belongs here or not...

When I create a new XPage, then drag the Single Page Application from the Mobile panel to the XPage I am not getting the Wizard?

I am using Designer 9.0.1, have installed the current OpenNTF ExtLib (901v00_03.20140120-0650) from OpenNTF and made sure that the correct version is referenced on both the Server (using the tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib command) and in Designer (About / Designer / Plug-in Details).

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanking you in advance
Ursus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Extension Library release comes with a couple of updateSite zips inside of it:

```
updateSiteOpenNTF.zip
updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip
updateSiteOpenTNTFExtended.zip
updateSiteOpenNTFSamples.zip
```

Be sure you are using the **updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip**, and not the standard updateSiteOpenNTF.zip. The designer zip, as the name suggests, contains the extlib content specifically for Designer, such as the Single App Wizard, as well as the rest of the extlib plugins that come in the first zip file listed above.

Comment: Documentation if you need it: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+XPages+Extension+Library#action=openDocument&res_title=Installing_the_OpenNTF_update_site_in_Domino_Designer_ddxl853&content=pdcontent

Comment: Brian, thank you for your input. That fixed my problem. I assumed that the server and the designer needed the EXACT same vesion...i.e. I installed both using the updateSiteOpenNTF.zip. Thanx again